# Save object to file with BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#

i want to save my list into a text file , so i convert it into an array,and now i want to write it down.

```
        public void Save(Group g)
    {
        string[] lines = g.elementsList.ConvertAll(p => p.ToString()).ToArray();
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (Stream file = File.OpenWrite(path)) 
        {
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bf.Serialize(ms, lines);
                    byte[] ser = ms.ToArray();

                    <--------stuck here :(

                }
            }
        }
```

how do i continue from here? or should i changed the whole approach..

Answer (score 2):

`BinaryFormatter` does not write text; if you want to write text *don't use `BinaryFormatter`*. Equally, you are currently writing `lines` each time, rather than `line`. But that is all academic: all of this is just:

```
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

That's it; that's the entire code to do this.

Comment: yeah but i want later on to load the info from that file.

Comment: @darko `File.ReadAllLines` ? More context (i.e. some invented sample data) would be helpful if you need more explanation